# Written group element as a power of commuting element

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

This question is a sentence in a quantum information paper, I was assuming the proof is easy...but I had a hard time on proving one of the directions. Maybe I am overlooking some very basic fact...Here is the question:

Let  $h_1,\ldots,h_r,g$ be commuting elements of an arbitrary group $G$, with order $s_1,\ldots,s_r,s$ respectively. Define $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_{s_1}\times \cdots\times \mathbb{Z}_{s_r}\times \mathbb{Z}_s\to G$ such that $$\phi(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_r,\alpha)=h_1^{\alpha_1}\ldots h_r^{\alpha_r}g^{-\alpha}.$$
Let $(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_r,\alpha)$ be in the kernel of $\phi$. 
Then $\alpha$ and $s$ are co-primes if and only if $g$ is representable as a product of power of $h_i$'s. I am ok with .. if co-prime, then.. part, but not quite sure how to proceed the converse direction part.

**EDITED**: Just to make sure I didn't misunderstand anything, I also attached a screenshot of the paper.

Could someone help me, thanks!

[image]

and the task (b) is so called constructive membership test, which is the following:

[image]

Comment: The statement is false. You always have $(0,0,\ldots,0,s)$ in the kernel, regardless of whether $g$ can be written as a product of the $h_i$ or not; here, $\alpha=s$, which is not relatively prime to $s$.

Comment: On the other hand, if we assume the $\alpha$ is the smallest positive integer such that there exist $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_r$ with $(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_r,\alpha)$ in the kernel, then the assertion does hold.

Comment: Hi @ArturoMagidin, thanks for the comment, and sorry for the late reply. Yes, I agree with you with your first comment. Could you help me to elaborate your second comment? Thanks

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Also...I guess as $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}_s$, we don't "really" have $\alpha=s$...

Comment: Doesn’t matter: you still have $(0,0,\ldots,0)$ in the kernel, where $\alpha=0$, and that happens no matter whether $g$ is equal to a power of the $h$s or not (and $\gcd(0,s)=s\neq 1$ if $s\neq 1$). There are extra assumptions in there that are not being stated.

Comment: (“Being in $\mathbb{Z}_s$”; that just means that you take integers and you assume they are equivalent if they are congruent modulo $s$. It does **not** mean that you are restricted to values between $0$ and $s-1$)

Comment: And even assuming you require $\alpha$ to satisfy $0\lt \alpha\lt s$, it’s still false as stated. Suppose $r=1$, $g=h_1$, and $s=s_1=4$. You still have $(2,2)$ in the kernel, and $2$ is not relatively prime to $4$.

Comment: Hi @ArturoMagidin, thanks! I have added two screenshots of the paper. Could you please help me to see what is going on? (I hope I didn't misunderstand anything from the paper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the screenshots it is clear where the error lies: you have misinterpreted/misrepresented the claim in the paper, and are thus trying to prove a false statement.

Namely, what the paper asserts is:

> There exists an element of the kernel with last coordinate relatively prime to $s$ if and only if $g$ can be expressed as a product of the $h$s.

What you are trying to prove (which is false) is:

> If $\mathbf{x}$ is in the kernel, then the last coordinate of $\mathbf{x}$ is relatively prime to $s$ if and only if $g$ can be expressed as a product of the $h$s.

They are different statements; in one direction, the former statement is an **existential** statement about elements in the kernel with desired properties, whereas what you have attempted to prove is a **universal** statement about such elements. The paper asserts that when $g$ can be expressed as a product of the $h$s, then there *exist* elements in the kernel with last coordinate relatively prime to $s$. What you have are trying to prove is that if $g$ can be expressed as a product of the $h$s, then *an arbitrary element of the kernel* (and hence, that *every* element of the kernel) will necessarily have last coordinate relatively prime to $s$. And that statement is false.

Simply: if $g$ can be expressed as a product of the $h_i$, $g=h_1^{a_1}\cdots h_r^{a_r}$, then $(a_1,\ldots,a_r,1)$ lies in the kernel, and the last coordinate, $1$, is relatively prime to $s$. Conversely, if you can find an element in the kernel with last coordinate relatively prime to $s$, say $(b_1,\ldots,b_r,\alpha)$, then find $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x\alpha + ys = 1$. Then $(xb_1,\ldots,xb_r,x\alpha)$ lies in the kernel, which yields
$$\begin{align*}
h_1^{xb_1}\cdots h_r^{xb_r}g^{-x\alpha} &= 1\\
h_1^{xb_1}\cdots h_r^{xb_r}&= g^{x\alpha}\\
h_1^{xb_1}\cdots h_r^{xb_r}&= g^{x\alpha}(g^s)^y\\
h_1^{xb_1}\cdots h_r^{xb_r}&= g^{x\alpha+sy}\\
h_1^{xb_1}\cdots h_r^{xb_r}&= g,
\end{align*}$$
so $g$ can be expressed as a product of the $h$s.

A counterexample to the claim you stated is given with $r=1$, $s=s_1=4$, and $g=h_1$. Then $g$ can be expressed as a product of the $h$s, but the kernel is equal to $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(2,2)$, and $(3,3)$; and while there *are* elements in the kernel with last coordinate relatively prime to $4$, not *every* element of the kernel has last coordinate relatively prime to $4$, even if we restrict to non-trivial elements.

Comment: Ah! How stupid I am! Thanks!